# scrolling in custom uitable view controllers does not work

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Well I do have a table view controller and is each cell I have assigned my own class. My table view loads normally but there is no scrolling. In the inspector windows I can not see any options in order to enable scrolling.

My code is here:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    myimages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...//definition of array with 22 images, its sure that everyone exists and I am writing them without the .png




}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tracksimages_closed count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Configure the cell...
    //getting the identifier
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"SimpleTableCell";
    //this is the identifier of the custom cell
    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

@end
```

This is my CustomTableCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mainImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: The attributes inspector value is `Scrolling enabled`, also check for `User Interaction Enabled`. Do your custom cells capture touches, could you post that code?

Comment: User Interaction Enabled is checked for my custom cell. Watch my edit for extra code. I cannot find that attribute "Scrolling Enabled" neither on my custom cell nor in my uitableview controller.

Comment: `scrollEnabled` is a property of the UITableView, not the UITableViewController or UITableViewCell.  (Actually it is a property of UIScrollView, from which UITableView inherits)

Comment: It's not either.. I only see: wants full screen, hide bottom bar on push, resize view from nib (which is checked). I am using xCode 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that NSArray had to be "retain". i do not know why, but it worked.

In particular my declaration was like this:

```
   myimages= [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"data_1",...,nil]retain]
```

Comment: Ok please close /delete your question, it's unlikely to be a helpful resource for others, since it's long and retain already has many questions on stackoverflow